# Chebyshev filter analog in computer vision?

Tags: filters, computer-vision, edge-detection, chebyshev-filters

Looking at the basic characteristics of a Chebyshev Filter, I was wondering if there were any analogous type filters in Computer Vision? The way that it can minimize the error between the idealized and the actual filter characteristic sounds a lot like edge detection to me.

Is there an analog between these to? If not, would it be useful to have such a thing in Computer Vision, or am I completely missing something?

Comment: I dunno exactly what you mean with *"filters in Computer Vision"*.  Can you develop that concept a little more?

Comment: An example I gave was for edge detection. Here we use convolutions with, for instance, a sobel filter. I understand that this is something completely different, but what I want to know if we were to use some adjusted form of a Chebyshev filter, if it could be used in the frequency domain of an image to detect edges, for instance?

Comment: Okay, I understand that the [Sobel Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) is applying a form of a differentiator along the x-axis while, at the same time, is applying the inverse operator (a sorta LPF) along the y-axis ***and*** then it does it again to the same original image but swapping what happens along the x and y axes.  Then the two results are squared, added, and square rooted.  The result exhibits edges and it appears to be independent of rotation.

Comment: You can apply a Tchebyshev filter (LPF along one axis and HPF along the other) and do it again, swapping the axes, square them both, add that result and square root.  See what you get.  I dunno enough about image processing to know if this is useful.

Comment: So, in summary, if you use a modified Chebyshev polynomial to find a good threshold value for separating edges from non-edges in the gradient image (not the frequency domain), which should probably be derived from an enhanced image? 

I will try your approach and see what I get! Sounds interesting, thank you!

Comment: A Type 2 Chebyshev filter is a prototype for a continuous-time filter that uses the Chebyshev polynomials in such a way that the passband is flat and the side lobes are equal in size and as small as possible.  Now edge detection needs a highpass filter of some sort to emphasize changes (a lowpass filter does the opposite and smooths out changes).  In traditional signal processing, a Chebyshev filter does not apply or fit polynomials to the data getting filtered.  It's a mathematical way to do a lowpass or highpass or bandpass filter that has equal-sized lobes in the stopband.